# ¿Error en la siguiente variable de sesión?

Tags: php, variables, sesiones

Esta aplicación debe tomar 4 números del formulario (va y viene de un archivo a otro) y debe mostrar número mayor y el número menor.

Formulario - ejercicio3.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="ejercicio3b.php" method="post">
 Insertar número: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="numero"/><br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Insertar"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Procesar - ejercicio3b.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$numero=($_POST['numero']);
$_SESSION["contador"]=$_SESSION["contador"]+1;
$contador=$_SESSION["contador"];
if($contador<5)
 {
 if($numero>$_SESSION["mayor"])
  {
  $_SESSION["mayor"]=$numero;
  }
 if($numero<$_SESSION["menor"])
  {
  $_SESSION["menor"]=$numero;

  }
  /*header("location:ejercicio3.php");*/
 }
else
echo "El mayor es " . $_SESSION["mayor"];
echo "El menor es " . $_SESSION["menor"];
session_destroy();
?>
```

Devuelvo los siguientes errores:

> Notice: Undefined index: contador in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ejerciciosVarios/ejercicio3b.php
>   on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: mayor in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ejerciciosVarios/ejercicio3b.php
>   on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: menor in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ejerciciosVarios/ejercicio3b.php
>   on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: menor in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ejerciciosVarios/ejercicio3b.php
>   on line 22

¡Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Puedes proporcionar el codigo en el que creas la sesion y los indices contador, mayor y menor?

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero iniciar tus variables o validar si tus variables de sesión en verdad tienen valor mediante [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) ya que en este caso seguramente no lo tienen, por eso el mensaje de error:

> Notice: Undefined index: ??? in

Ejemplos:

```
//$numero=($_POST['numero']);
$numero= isset( $_POST['numero'] ) ? $_POST['numero'] : "<valor default>";

//$contador=$_SESSION["contador"];
$contador=isset( $_SESSION["contador"] ) ? $_SESSION["contador"] : "<valor default>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes definir los valores iniciales para la primera ejecución:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Verificar que exista el contador en sesión
if(!isset($_SESSION['contador'])) {
    $_SESSION['contador'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['menor'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['mayor'] = 0;
}
// Aquí comienzas a analizar el número
// y actualizas las variables de sesión
```